# Ubuntu 17.10 Suspend not resuming

Tags: gnome, xorg, suspend, power-management

I'm on an Acer Espire with intel microcode running dual boot Xorg 17.10 using Gnome. I'd say it's usually 50/50 that i'm able to suspend and successfully resume. When I suspend, the monitor will go out but the hard drive will still be running and I have to hard power off. Here's a pm-suspend log:

```
    Initial commandline parameters: 
Fri Dec 22 16:24:14 EST 2017: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
Linux qs-ubuntu 4.14.8-041408-generic #201712200555 SMP Wed Dec 20 10:57:38 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
msr                    16384  0
ccm                    20480  6
binfmt_misc            20480  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
ath3k                  20480  0
uvcvideo               86016  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
videodev              176128  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
cmdlinepart            16384  0
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             540672  6 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,ath3k,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
intel_spi_platform     16384  0
intel_spi              20480  1 intel_spi_platform
spi_nor                32768  1 intel_spi
joydev                 20480  0
mtd                    57344  4 spi_nor,intel_spi,cmdlinepart
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  4
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             204800  0
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
kvm                   589824  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_soc_rt5640        118784  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          229376  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm                98304  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core,snd_soc_rt5640,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_soc_core
pcbc                   16384  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
aesni_intel           188416  4
arc4                   16384  2
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
ath9k                 151552  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
ath9k_hw              462848  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_hw,ath9k,ath9k_common
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
mac80211              778240  1 ath9k
cfg80211              614400  4 mac80211,ath9k,ath,ath9k_common
snd                    77824  21 snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
input_leds             16384  0
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
hid_multitouch         20480  0
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
soundcore              16384  1 snd
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
snd_soc_sst_match      16384  1 snd_soc_sst_acpi
shpchp                 36864  0
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
dw_dmac                16384  0
soc_button_array       16384  0
8250_dw                16384  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
elan_i2c               36864  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
mac_hid                16384  0
acer_wmi               20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
i915                 1572864  20
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  81920  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mii                    16384  1 r8169
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
rtsx_pci               57344  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
drm                   376832  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  4
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    24576  2 wmi_bmof,acer_wmi
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
video                  40960  2 acer_wmi,i915
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  2 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        5994980     1088328     3650684      262324     1255968     4398808
Swap:             0           0           0
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/40inputattach suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/40inputattach suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/49tlp suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/49tlp suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Selected interface 'wlp2s0'
OK
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend:
Warning: Stopping anacron.service, but it can still be activated by:
  anacron.timer
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
Kernel modesetting video driver detected, not using quirks.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.

Fri Dec 22 16:24:15 EST 2017: performing suspend
```

This is beyond frustrating as I've been looking for a solution for weeks if not months to no avail. I tried upgrading the kernel which didn't work. I'm new to linux so please bear with me and let me know if there's anything else I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed with the latest Ubuntu kernel update **4.13.0.19.20**. Try suspend after upgrade kernel.
Source : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1725788

Comment: I upgraded to 4.14.8-041408-generic yesterday. Do you recommend I downgrade?

Comment: Nope. Did you visit and read source link. I think it will help you!

Comment: So i’m suspending via systemctl suspend and it seems to be going smoothly so far (3 for my last 3) .. but I just went to shut down and I froze on the purple Ubuntu screen

Comment: I opened a bug here, as this didn't work for me.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1740175